# SQL Group by on a single column and repeating that value across other rows in same group

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb

Suppose we have a table that looks like this

```
greeting | animal | freq
--------------------------
hello    | dog    | 1
hello    | cat    | 3
nice     | dog    | 1
day      | dog    | 2
```

How do we group by "greetings" and sum up "freq" while keeping distinct records for the "animal" column?

The query should result in:

```
greeting | animal | freq_sum
-----------------------------
hello    | dog    | 4             <-- value is the sum of the two "hello" records' freq value
hello    | cat    | 4
nice     | dog    | 1
day      | dog    | 2
```

I know we can do

```
select greeting, animal, count(freq) as freq_sum
from table
group by greeting
```

However, this results in a single record from each group (and I am assuming it is doing an implicit MAX on the animal column?) and instead I want that aggregated sum value to be repeated across all the rows with the same group.

Your advice will be truly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on maria db 10.2 or higher then you can use the windows function as follows:

```
select greeting, animal, sum(freq) over (partition by greeting) as freq_sum
from table
```